# Server Error in appspot.com application

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, python-2.7, google-calendar-api

Running my application on local with `dev_appserver` for finding event list from Google calendar and it works fine.

when I deployed through app-engine (deployment done successful) and when I run the file it gives me below error

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.
```

Google lot about this error still unable to find solution for the same

my `app.yaml` file structure.

```
- url: /calendar
  script: webserverflow12.py
```

When I run this `appspot.com/calendar`. It is giving me mentioned error.

Any idea what changes need to do to run my application on live?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you didn't changed your client id and client secret which u registered for appspot.com domain when deploying to appengine server. So you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application logs from your GAE admin page.
Hopefully you'll find some info there to help debug.